# Java Reentrant Locks: Second thread can't get lock

Tags: java, multithreading, reentrantlock

I have just started using synchronous methods in Java and I have made a basic application that uses an reentrant lock

this is what it is suppose to do:
One thread will access the locked class first by locking to prevent conflict. Once the first thread has finished incrementing then the second thread will do the same.

My problem is that, after unlocking, the first threads stated that It had already unlocked while the second thread will still receive a locked status, meaning it is starved.

Here is my code

main class

```
public class JavaApplication3 {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        SynchronizedInt s = new SynchronizedInt();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new FlameThread(s));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new FlameThread(s));
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
    }
}
```

lock class

```
public class SynchronizedInt {
    private int count;
    private Lock l;

    public SynchronizedInt() {
        this.count = 0;
        this.l = new ReentrantLock();
    }

    public synchronized void addCounter() {
        this.count++;
        ThreadMessage.print(Integer.toString(this.count));
    }

    public synchronized Lock getLock() {
        return l;
    }
}
```

Thread Class

```
public class FlameThread implements Runnable {
    private SynchronizedInt s;

    public FlameThread(SynchronizedInt s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            try {
                try{
                    while(!this.s.getLock().tryLock()){
                        ThreadMessage.print(""+this.s.getLock().tryLock());
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                    this.s.getLock().lock();
                    this.s.addCounter();
                }finally{
                    this.s.getLock().unlock();
                }
                ThreadMessage.print(""+this.s.getLock().tryLock());
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FlameThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ThreadMessage

```
public class ThreadMessage {
    // Display a message, preceded by
    // the name of the current thread
    public static void print(String message) {
        String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.format("%s: %s%n", threadName, message);
    }
}
```

Results

```
run:
Thread-0: 1
Thread-0: true
Thread-1: false
Thread-0: 2
Thread-1: false
Thread-0: true
Thread-0: 3
Thread-1: false
Thread-0: true
Thread-0: 4
Thread-1: false
Thread-0: true
```

EDIT #1:

expected output

```
run:
Thread-0: 1
Thread-0: true
Thread-1: false
Thread-1: 2
Thread-1: true
Thread-0: false
Thread-0: 3
Thread-0: true
Thread-1: false
...
```

A single thread should not hog all the locks

EDIT #2:

Fixed the problem.

Apparently, I should had not used trylock.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include the output you were expecting?

Answer (score 0):

You are literally acquiring the lock in threa.run 4 times, using lock and tryLock, and only release it once. Even worse: you relock it just after you released it. The implication is that the lock remains locked after the first thread finished.

As your SynchronizedInt already uses the synchronized keyword, you don't even need a lock here. Moreover, you don't even need a synchronizedInt class, you can just use the builtin AtomicInt.

Comment: I didn't know that it will remain locked until the thread exits, thank you.